# Django AJAX: CSRF Verification failed says csrf token is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

So I am trying to retreive json serialized data from django webserver, and I am keep getting an error 403 says that the csrf verification failed due to token missing or incorrect.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var invsearch = $('[name="invsearch"]')
    invsearch.keyup(function(){
        var ooid = invsearch.val();
        if(ooid.length > 3){
            $.ajax({
                url:'{% url 'ofsomething' %}',
                data:{
                    invoice_id:ooid,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                datatype:"json",
                type:'POST',
                success: function(json){
                    var orders = JSON.parse(json);
                    console.log(orders.length);
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
                    console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So I included csrfmiddlewaretoken field in data. What did I do wrong here?

By the way, this script is inside the template so I could use the block tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
```

to

```
"csrfmiddlewaretoken": $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
```